# iPhone 4S (iOS 6.1.1) Activity log

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to see report in system files of when my iPhone was switched on and switched off like in Windows Event viewer

System report like this 5.06.14 11:12 power on 8.06.14 20:10 power off

I have Jailbroken iPhone with iFile installed and access to all system files.

Maybe this information available in /var/mobile/Library/Logs ? Because some of applications that monitors system in AppStore shows only runtime in seconds which is completely useless. Thanks in advance for reply!

Answer (score 0):

iBackupbot does this without a jailbreak!! I can't really remember how, but it's not to complicated.

For on-device syslog

install "Big Boss recommended tools" then open or install MobileTerminal

Run "ondeviceconsole"

BOOM!! It's even colored!!